# submit form from popup window - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a FORM in parent window ,

```
<form id="myform">
<username>
<password>
</form>
```

and in jQuery

```
$("#myform").submit(function(e){

e.preventDefault(); // prevent default form submit

//some of my other codes ...

});
```

and i am using `window.open` to open a new window

```
var popupWindow =  window.open("myUrl");
```

From the popup window i am trying to submit the `myform` form

```
$(window.opener.document.getElementById("myform")).submit();
```

the form is getting submitted , but the problem is that it using the default form submission instead of my attached event.

What i am doing wrong ?

Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please show how you have attached the handler

Comment: Sorry, got it. Saw it late. Is the handler attached in the parent form or in the popup window?

Comment: the form submission handler attached in parent window , it have many calculations,process etc ...

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have working:

Parent.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Try Me..." onclick='window.open("Child.html");' />
    <form action="post.html" method="post" id="myForm">

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Child.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function submitParent() {

            window.opener.document.forms["myForm"].submit();
            window.close();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="submitParent();" value="Submit Parent" />
</body>
</html>
```

When clicking on "Submit Parent" it closes the Child, and it Submits the parent to "Post.html".

Good Luck!

Comment: @john Why is it not working? It should work if the form myForm has a submit button right?

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

I realized that  the event attached through jQuery is not working if the event is triggered from some other resources.

But it works well with pure-js with inline event ,

```
<form id="myform" onsubmit=" process(); "></form>
```

and it works well.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this

```
        <div id="divform">
            <form action="/system/wpacert" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="certform">
                <div>Certificate 1: <input type="file" name="cert1"/></div>
                <div>Certificate 2: <input type="file" name="cert2"/></div>

                <div><input type="button" value="Upload" onclick="closeSelf();"/></div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div  id="closelink" style="display:none">
            <a href="javascript:window.close()">Click Here to Close this Page</a>
        </div>

function closeSelf(){
    document.forms['certform'].submit();
    hide(document.getElementById('divform'));
    unHide(document.getElementById('closelink'));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're opening a new window when you use `window.open`. That starts a new thread. You don't have access to the same DOM context and the elements and events contained within it.

Comment: you are wrong , i have access to the DOM , because the new thread is started ny parent thread , if i dont have permission to access then how can i communicate with threads ?